# Processing line scanner data

Tags: image-processing, feature-detection

I have a line scanner output that is scanning the geometry of a surface. Typically the output looks something like this:

[image]

Where the x and y axis refers to the coordinate system in mm. (ignore the red dots). This data is essentially a 2d point cloud.

So what i am trying to achieve is to detect the corner points of this scan. I try to start using image processing techniques, for example using a harris corner detector.

However, the issue with this is that this data has a resolution of up to 0.01um vs a possible area size of 140mm X 100mm of all possible data points. If i were to convert this to 2d image, it would be a very large file, with most of the pixels being empty.

My question is that is there a better way to go about processing this type of data; or is there an alternative way to apply techniques such as the harris corner without resorting to conversion into an image.

Comment: I would work with the 2d pointclound (feels like better data to work with). Initially I'd simplify the path. There are multiple algorithms, [RDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) being one of them. (OpenCV has it implement it already as [approxPolyDP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp). Then I would loop through the points in pair (e.g. current and previous or current and next) and check the angle between them (within a certain threshold will be corners).

Comment: In case you do end up going the image based approach (reduced resolution, perhaps), take a look at the following paper: http://rsl.iim.ac.cn/faculty/ymli/docs/papers/LiICRA10.pdf

Comment: How many *"corners"* do you expect the algorithm to find in your diagram and where are they?

Comment: @MarkSetchell It will be at each turning point, at x= -2, 10, 18

Comment: Can you share the point data?

Comment: Will there always be three corners?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Unfortunately I don't have the point data with me. But yes, there will be 3 corners.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the contour points are recorded "in order", e.g. clockwise, you can perform the following algorithm without converting to images at all (otherwise, prepare your contour in that form):

1. For each point on the closed contour (periodic boundary condition): calculate local discretized curvature by considering the points N steps (or for the case of unevenly spaced points "at least N pixels distance") behind and in front of the current point. Your choice of N determines the noise suppression level. To make sure it is appropriate, do something like a 3D plot (x,y = point coordinates, z = calculated curvature) for different values of N. The actual corners should stand out nicely.
2. Once you are satisfied with N: During performing step 1, record all results as a e.g. vector of tuples describing {point coordinates, curvature}. Once you are done, sort the vector by absolute value of curvature (or record abs(curvature) to begin with).
3. Step through sorted vector from highest to lowest curvature. Record highest curvature point as a corner. For each subsequent high-curvature point, record it as a corner if there is not yet a recorded (higher curvature of same sign) corner within X pixels distance (this prevents double detections of the same corner). X should be close to N, but you might need to fine-tune if you need to detect closely spaced S- or M-shaped curves. It is also sensible to introduce a cut-off minimum curvature required to consider a point a corner (depends on your noise level).

If n = number of contour points, curvature calculations run in O(n) without needing to go to an image representation. Determining the corners is theoretically worst-case O(n²), but in practice often much faster. This latter de facto performance depends on the number of significant corners on your contour (relatively low, from your description), and the noise level where you can effectively cut the corner search off.

edit: 
If you are considering simplifying the point cloud to reduce complexity or running time, note that contour simplification itself is already O(n*log(n)). Depending on the shape of your contours and the reduction algorithm complexity, that might potentially slow your algorithm down as opposed to using the large number of contour points.